# Calling EF6 FindAsync hangs the application

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, async-await

I'm trying to use Entity Framework 6's Async calls, but whenever I call the `FindAsync`, the application hangs, and I never get the control back. Below is the method using the `Find`, where everything goes fine.

```
public CaUsuario GetUsers(RFContext db, int id)
{
        CaUsuario caUsuario = db.CaUsuarios.Find(id);
        if (caUsuario == null)
                throw new ObjectNotFoundException("User not found");
        return caUsuario;
}
```

Below is my attempt to use the `async`, with `Task` return a the `ASync` call. When the `FindAsync` is called, I never receive the control back, and the application hangs.

```
public async Task<CaUsuario> GetUsers(RFContext db, int id)
{
    CaUsuario caUsuario = await db.CaUsuarios.FindAsync(id);
    if (caUsuario == null)
        throw new ObjectNotFoundException("User not found");
    return caUsuario;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you calling the async `GetUsers`?

Comment: You are probably not doing async all the way through your call chain/stack. Using a combination of Task<T>.Result and await in the call chain will cause a deadlock.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov you nailed it .. it was a problem on how I was calling. Post it as answer, so that you can get the credit. Thank you so much. First time I use it. Never would've thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might hang in the event of not going "async all the way". Ensure that whatever is calling into the `GetUsers` is doing so with the `async` and `await` keywords, and not incorrectly attempting to use the `.Result` or `.Wait()`.

Assume the following is a consuming class:

```
public class Consumer
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    public Consumer(IUserService  userService)
    {
       _userService = userService;
    }

    public async Task ConsumeAsync()
    {
        // Correct
        var user = await _userService.GetUsers(1);
    }

    public void Consume()
    {
        // Will hang
        var user = _userService.GetUsers(1).Result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not doing async all the way through your call chain/stack. Using a combination of `Task<T>.Result` and `await` in the call chain will cause a deadlock.